# Can "by the time" used in different tenses? If yes then show me

Tags: word-usage

Can "by the time" used in different tenses? If yes then show me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in a sense:

> By the time you arrive the party will be over.

We’re saying this before the party.

> By the time I arrived the party was over.

We’re saying this after the party.

You can think of “by” in “by the time” as meaning “at”, except that unlike “at the time”, “by the time” tends to have a strong focus/emphasis on the period before “the time”, and what is going on there in relation to what is going on at “the time”.

For example:

> By the time you’ve chopped the vegetables, the oven will have heated.